# Is it still possible to embed an Instagram user's content in a website?

Tags: embed, instagram

I've been trying to figure out how to get my Instagram photos to display on my website. Every method my Google searches have turned up is broken. I think Instagram may have recently changed their API.

[Instafeed.js](http://instafeedjs.com/) seemed promising but I keep getting the error "access_token provided is invalid." I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct user ID. None of the utilities for finding user IDs work anymore but in the source code for my profile page there's a JSON object where the same ID number appears 14 times and I'm pretty sure it's my user ID. The client ID I got from https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ after registering a new client. I don't understand what could be invalid about my access token.

Why is this so hard? I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I'm a web developer. I can't imagine that a lay person would have any chance of making this work. You'd think Instagram would want to make it easy for people to do this.

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because it is about API programming. Stack Overflow is ideally where this question should go but they will expect code, and log reports from the API.

Comment: Sorry about that. I started to post there but then thought this might be more appropriate. I'll take my question there. Thanks!

Comment: Try talking to the API manually, without the GitHub project. It could be just a case that that project is outdated and Instagram have updated there API since. Facebook, Twitter, Instagram and other major social networks often update there API's, and its common to see open source projects require Git PUSH with the changes in order for it to work.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they introduced a major change on June 1. I just can't believe they don't provide a way to do this the way Twitter does. It seems ridiculous that we have to go to all this trouble to share our own public content.

Comment: Sadly, your find when using any popular API, it requires regular updates.

Comment: Always be sure to click (issues) on GitHub, your issue has been mentioned here: https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/408

Comment: Just 3 days ago :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember this for next time. I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. :)